# Netbeans multiple project in the project windows

Tags: java, netbeans

Is there any way for have multiple projects in Netbeans in organized way?
Like JDeveloper for example.
When I have multiple projects in the "Projects windows" a module of a project confused with another project, if they have the same name is not easy to know which project belongs.

The structure in maven Netbeans, is

- Projects1
- Module1
- Module2
- Module3
- Projects2
- Module1
- Module2
- Module3

Whole projects and modules (the module belong to projects) are in the same level,

I organized this way for the example, the actually order is:

- Projects1
- Projects2
- Module1
- Module1
- Module2
- Module2
- Module3
- Module3

Which is the module1 of Projects1? Which is the module3 oof Projects2? Is very difficult to know.

My question is, there are any way for stucture like this:

- Projects1

  |_Module1

  |_Module2
- Projects2

  |_Module1

  |_Module2

  |_Module3

Etc.... Or each projects in their own windows

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. If you want to have multiple projects in the "Projects" window then just open the additional ones (File -> Open Project). If you want to switch between related projects use Project groups: https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb81/netbeans/develop/working_nbeans.htm#NBDAG2209

Comment: You are not suppose to have more than one project with the same name

Comment: Thanks by your answer, I explain my question.
The structure in maven Netbeans, is 

Projects1
Module1
Module2
Module3
Projects2
Module1
Module2
Module3

Whole projects and modules (the module belong to projects) is in the same level, I organized this way for the example, the actually order is:

Projects1
Projects2
Module1
Module1
Module2
Module2
Module3
Module3

Which is the module1 of Projects1? Which is the projects2?
My question is, There are any way for stucture like this:
Projects1
 |_Module1
 |_Module2
Porjecs2
Etc....
Or each projects in their own windows.

Comment: Please add these details directly in your question by editing it. It will be much more readable.